# how to parse findstr result into a cmd variable to allow stripping of found line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to extract a version number out of an XML file. The XML file contains as string with:

`<!-- Full version --> 
<key id="about_fullVersion">10.1.5</key>`

Using:

```
FINDstr /I "about_fullVersion" C:\PLM\Teamcenter10\install\versionlocal.xml >>%logfile%
```

I can extract the complete line and send it to the log file.
How can I strip the version number from this find so that I only send the version# to the logfile ?

I also tried

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('FINDstr /I "about_fullVersion" C:\PLM\Teamcenter10\install\versionlocal.xml') do (set var=%%a)
echo.%var% >>%logfile%
```

but it does not parse to the variable.

Comment: I am glad you have something that works for you. In general, scanning HTML/XML with cmd scripts, or even regexes, is a fool's errand. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set VAR=&
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=<>" %%v in (`
  findstr /i "about_fullVersion" C:\PLM\Teamcenter10\install\versionlocal.xml
`) do if not defined VAR set VAR=%%v
echo VAR="%VAR%"
```

Comment: @Arjen: If the answer has solved the problem then please accept it, so that future readers know that it worked.